# How to make a thesis that can be read from both sides?

Tags: thesis

Soon I will have to hand in my thesis for my PhD. For my thesis I want to make a book that consists of two parts. You open on one side and you read the first part and turn it over to read the other part. Does anyone know how to make this in LateX? Is there a package for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are your sure the PhD commission or your supversor(s) will appreciate such a style? or do you just want to annoy them? ;-)

Comment: How much textual/typesetting interdependency is there between the two parts — e.g. will they have a single shared bibliography, or two separate bibliographies?  If the two parts are mostly independent, then it might be easiest to typeset them separately with LaTeX, and then stitch the pdf’s together afterwards with a pdf editing tool.

Comment: Would be funny to see how this works with requirements like "first page must contain foo, last page must be bar"

Comment: Oooops.... `supversor` should read `supervisor` of course... Sorry...

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments! @ChristianHupfer: The final printed version would be like that, not the electronic version because that is really annoying indeed.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: I think I want them to be mostly independent. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 12):

Here is a 'stupid' idea:

Write two separate docs and include them as 1st part with regular order and the second one with the pages in reversed order and rotated.

Alternatively: Write one doc and choose the page range explicitly, which should go for the first part and as well for the 2nd (reversed) part.

The easiest way is `\includepdf`from `pdfpages` package -- but this will lose the cross-referencing and hyperlinks, but the later are for a printed document not really useful. `ToC` etc. is little bit difficult, but should be possible.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\title{How to annoy people}
\author{A.U Thor}
\date{2063/4/5}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{dummydoc1.pdf}

\includepdf[pages=last-1,angle=-180]{dummydoc2.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Here is `dummydoc1.tex` (and `dummydoc2.tex` is pretty much the same.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section{Beginning \jobname}
\blindtext[50]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! Let me see if I can make this idea work for me :)

Comment: @physicist: Since there are no other answers yet, consider to accept my answer, please